# Deadlock with read and update on snapshot isolation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

On a table that is heavily used with reads and writes, a lot of deadlocks are happening. Therefore I am experimenting with snapshot isolation. As I understood, reads shouldn't block writes and writes schouldn't block reads. Unfortunately, there are still deadlocks with those operations as shown below.

Am I wrong with my expectation, that those deadlocks should not happen with snapshot isolation?

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="processe587a9088">
  <process-list>
   <process id="processe587a9088" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 11:72057594050904064 (d6a2e023f14e)" waittime="2359" ownerId="1218373" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2022-11-18T13:58:58.453" XDES="0xe75e35c60" lockMode="RangeS-S" schedulerid="15" kpid="636" status="suspended" spid="65" sbid="0" ecid="13" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2022-11-18T13:58:58.453" lastbatchcompleted="2022-11-18T13:58:58.453" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.453" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="SUN" hostpid="40632" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="1218373" currentdb="11" currentdbname="-rocket-author" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="170" stmtend="1324" sqlhandle="0x0200000057d81707bbdc50a55ae52cfd91db4d2b8ab0279f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@__result_TransactionId_0 uniqueidentifier,@__destinationInstanceKey_1 nvarchar(50))SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[EntityId], [c].[EntityType], [c].[Error], [c].[FailureCount], [c].[InstanceKey], [c].[ReplicationScheduleOptions], [c].[ReplicationType], [c].[ScheduledAt], [c].[ScheduledById], [c].[Status], [c].[TransactionId], [c].[Metadata_ModifiedAt], [c].[Metadata_ModifiedById], [c].[Metadata_PublishedAt], [c].[Metadata_PublishedById], [c].[Metadata_PublishedStage]
FROM [ReplicationSchedule] AS [c]
WHERE ([c].[TransactionId] = @__result_TransactionId_0) AND ([c].[InstanceKey] = @__destinationInstanceKey_1)    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="processe00051088" taskpriority="0" logused="1236" waitresource="KEY: 11:72057594050904064 (8a80a45c8553)" waittime="2336" ownerId="1216957" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2022-11-18T13:58:58.123" XDES="0xe00188428" lockMode="X" schedulerid="1" kpid="2044" status="suspended" spid="83" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2022-11-18T13:58:58.350" lastbatchcompleted="2022-11-18T13:58:58.347" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.347" clientapp="Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="SUN" hostpid="40632" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1216957" currentdb="11" currentdbname="-rocket-author" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="6" stmtstart="938" stmtend="1240" sqlhandle="0x0200000045b2f113b74c9df2726146dd46cbeb9155dda3010000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@p3 uniqueidentifier,@p0 int,@p1 datetimeoffset(7),@p2 uniqueidentifier,@p7 uniqueidentifier,@p4 int,@p5 datetimeoffset(7),@p6 uniqueidentifier,@p11 uniqueidentifier,@p8 datetimeoffset(7),@p9 uniqueidentifier,@p10 nvarchar(4000),@p13 uniqueidentifier,@p12 datetimeoffset(7))SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [ReplicationSchedule] SET [Status] = @p0, [Metadata_ModifiedAt] = @p1, [Metadata_ModifiedById] = @p2
WHERE [Id] = @p3;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

UPDATE [ReplicationSchedule] SET [Status] = @p4, [Metadata_ModifiedAt] = @p5, [Metadata_ModifiedById] = @p6
WHERE [Id] = @p7;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

UPDATE [GummyBearPack] SET [Metadata_PublishedAt] = @p8, [Metadata_PublishedById] = @p9, [Metadata_PublishedStage] = @p10
WHERE [Id] = @p11;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

UPDATE [GummyBearProductionCharge] SET [Metadata_PublishedAt] = @p12
WHERE [Id] = @p13;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594050904064" dbid="11" objectname="-rocket-author.dbo.ReplicationSchedule" indexname="PK_ReplicationSchedule" id="locke61bad100" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594050904064">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="processe00051088" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="processe587a9088" mode="RangeS-S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594050904064" dbid="11" objectname="-rocket-author.dbo.ReplicationSchedule" indexname="PK_ReplicationSchedule" id="locke106de100" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72057594050904064">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="processe587a9088" mode="RangeS-S"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="processe00051088" mode="X" requestType="convert"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snapshot database options are not relevant to the deadlock in your question.

The `SELECT` query session is using the `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation level (as shown by `isolationlevel="serializable (4)` in the `process` xml element), which is especially prone to deadlocks because of the more restrictive locking. `SERIALIZABLE` does not use row versioning and is unaffected by the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` or `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` database options. Note that, as @DavidBrowne-Microsoft mentioned in comments, .NET applications that use `TransactionScope` sometimes use `SERIALIZABLE` inadvertently since that's the default unless another isolation level is specified.

The `UPDATE` query session is using `READ COMMITTED` so read-only queries on that session will use row versioning because of the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON` database setting. However, data modifications still use locking for transactional integrity. Below is the excerpt from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments):

> **Important**
>
> Choosing a transaction isolation level does not affect the locks
> acquired to protect data modifications. A transaction always gets an
> exclusive lock on any data it modifies, and holds that lock until the
> transaction completes, regardless of the isolation level set for that
> transaction. Additionally, an update made at the READ_COMMITTED
> isolation level uses update locks on the data rows selected, whereas
> an update made at the SNAPSHOT isolation level uses row versions to
> select rows to update. For read operations, transaction isolation
> levels primarily define the level of protection from the effects of
> modifications made by other transactions.

This deadlock will be avoided if you change the `SELECT` query session to use `READ COMMITTED` or `SNAPSHOT` instead of `SERIALIZABLE`. With all sessions using an isolation level implemented with row versioning, readers will not block or deadlock with writers and visa-versa. Only writer/writer blocks/deadlocks can occur.

The `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` database option does not need to be set unless you plan to use the `SNAPSHOT` transaction isolation level.

Comment: @user2900970, I updated my answer for your first question. For existing applications I'm not intimately familiar with, my personal preference is to opt-in for `SNAPSHOT` isolation for read-only queries and leave `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF` to preserve pessimistic locking behavior of read/write transactions.